# Screen resolution and scale resets a couple of seconds after login into account. How to fix?

Tags: login, display, xrandr, display-resolution, scaling

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. My graphics card is an integrated Intel Graphics card, and my monitor is plugged through VGA. For some reason Ubuntu doesn't recognize my monitor's available resolutions and it used to give me only two options: 1024x768 and 800x600, defaulting to the former.

Now, I found that I could create the desired resolution (1280x1024, which is my tiny monitor's physical resolution) using xrandr, and I wrote this script to run at startup (when I log into my account) to fix the resolution automatically:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024"  108.70  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024
xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

(I saved it as cus_res_fix.sh at /home/ and added it to Startup Applications)

It worked just fine. But-

That resolution is not really pleasing since I was used to 1600x1200 on Windows (I know the real resolution cannot be larger than 1280x1024, but I liked all my stuff tiny, and I guess it had some nice supersampling effect, since 1280x1024 looks kinda blurry. Anyways-), but I can't create a mode for more than 1280x1024 from Ubuntu, because then my monitor says it can't display that resolution.

In the end, I decided to instead scale it. I changed the

```
xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

to

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --scale 1.25x1.25 --panning 1600x1028
```

logged in and it works and looks nice!  But-

A few seconds after I login, the scale goes back to normal, and I'm left with a "1280x1024" screen box and a lot of leftover black space. If I run

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.25x1.25 --panning 1600x1028
```

It'll work and stay like that indefinitely, but I don't want to have to do that every time.

I was wondering if you know what could be resetting the display scaling after every login, and if there's a way I could either disable whatever it is, or workaround it so that I can keep my resolution and scaling every time.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what it does it, but you can set a delay to the command that you do, with `sleep`, so that it will be executed after some time.

Comment: @dadexix86 But this doesn't seem to happen after a regular amount of time. None that I could figure out. I tried using my phone timer. Sometimes it's 10 after, sometimes it's 15.

Comment: Do you maybe have another program that takes sometime to fully start? It might be that this time varies accordingly (like Mega, Dropbox, Teamviewer, Chrome Remote Desktop...). What are the programs/services that you activate on boot?

Comment: Why not add `xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.25x1.25 --panning 1600x1028` as a startup command?